# After installation with WIX-Toolset MSI, text files unreadable

Tags: wix, windows-installer, asmx, file-format, wix3.10

we are working with the WIX-Toolset now for quiet sometime. It always was a sail in smooth waters, once we configured our XML like we wanted to have it installed no changes were needed for almost a year.
Until a week ago, we needed to build a new MSI for our customer.

We have several librarys writen in C#, which are included aswell as some javascript files and last but not least some ASMX Files which are our webservices.

As soon as we build a new MSI we create a new version of all of these files. Everything works good, even the javascript... but the ASMX Files are somewhat broken. They have a very specific online statement which allows to access the `C#` class in the background from the web. But the text files gets mal formated.
We build the file and copy it by hand, and everything works fine. If we use the MSI it gets broken.

We tried to pinpoint it down in the configuration and could not find any changes at all.
Strange thing is, we encode the Webservice asmx as UTF-8 after opening the asmx files in the target folder it is ANSI. What could cause this? Could this be the problem?
Next strange thing... all the files are 20Kb in size and are shown in Notepad++ with a length of 19968 characters in 411 lines. For all 4 different `ASMX`.

The Installation folder is `C:\Program Files\Product Name\Sub Product\website\Webservice\`

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Try running an administrative install of your MSI to see if the files are malformed from the start: msiexec.exe /a product.msi

Comment: Hi, have you solved the problem?

Comment: No unfortunately not. The installer has to be executed with admin privilege anyways, because it writes on the system partition on a windows server. Insufficient rights would cause that the user is not able to click next. We are using a zip file at the moment because we really dont know what's causing the problem. Even if we create a new installer project the issue remains...